# How to scale solve WebSocket connection when server goes down

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket, wss, java-websocket

Is it possible to store the web socket connection and use that for distributed the load.

For Example - Similar to what we have in AWS ALB to distribute the traffic.

Comment: One Solution - Client reconnect the connection after timeout of some interval. However this is from the client side solution.